# Why Azure Shared site is slower than Free site

Tags: azure

I deployed my website's dev version to Azure Free and my beta version to Azure Shared.

The same page it takes Free site 10 seconds to load, but it takes Shared site 30 seconds to load!!

Is there something wrong with Azure?! How can I contact them as they only provide billing support, but no tech support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to agree with the original question.  This is a real issue.  If I can confirm it I will post it again as a new question and issue with details.

I had my website in the shared plan and it was running blazingly fast, but... I hit my 512 meg limit and it 403'd.

I moved it to the $32/month basic, and its running 2-4 second lag on page retrieve.

I'm moving it up into premium levels now, but this is a real situation.

Note I'm an Azure Certified Developer ( 70-532 ), MCAD, and also a Microsoft Technology Evangelist in the field.

I'm planning on doing a deployment of the exactly same app to Shared, Basic1, Standard1, and Premium1.  I'm then going to load test both from azure and from local visual studio and we'll see what happens.

All my stuff is in East US2 right now.

This is a real issue, at least to me.

I'll keep this issue alive and keep you posted.

Healy in Tampa